# Windows chromium-browser fresh build stacktrace and anonymous fatal errors on runtime

Tags: windows, windows-10, chromium

Recently, I've started to put time and efforts into understanding the chromium-browser project. My goal is to eventually be able to contribute as a developper, so I ended up looking how to get it and build it locally. I am facing some issues when running it and cannot find any explanation just yet.

Hopefully it will help other people that are in the same situation. After looking quite a bit on forums, I didn't find something similar and would like to know if this is something I've missed.

I am trying to run chromium-browser on Windows 10 Home Edition. My current configuration is i5-2500k / 8gb DDR3 and my workspace is on a hard drive until I get a bigger SSD (The recommended specs are suggesting 16-32 GB of RAM and a SSD to allow it to build and run better. Can it be part of the problem?).

My current chromium build is: Version 54.0.2808.0 (64-bit)

To fetch and build the project, I've followed the instruction on how to get the code.

What I did is:

- Extracted the windows version of the depot-tools into my workspace
- Fetched the repositories with `fetch chromium` and `gclient runhooks`
- Built with `cd src`,  `gn gen out/Default` and `ninja -C out/Debug`

The build process does its job and no errors are showing up in console. However, when I launch the browser, I get multiple errors that seems to be related to the stacktrace. Those errors are not modal and as long as I don't close any of them, chrome keeps responding and pages are shown as expected so this is no big deal for now:

[image: StackTrace errors]

But, if I do some heavy loading (e.g.: loading the facebook news feed), it seems to hang and doesn't respond very well from this point (e.g.: endless loading, mouse events not working inside tab). It can also be reproduced on my end by going to https://www.google.ca and right-clicking anywhere on the page.

To try speeding things up a little bit, I've run a script to rename every pdb files so they are not attaching to the process. This greatly improves speed, but there are still errors. StackTrace errors become this:
[image: Errors when no PDB]

As for the hanging issue, it will now show an empty modal box suggesting an error (the description isn't too kind on what it is). This one is modal and once closed, chrome stops working as intended. What happens is the mouse over events don't show up, and the page will never finish loading when reloading it.
[image: Blank error]

I am aware that the latest version can be unstable sometimes, but I am working towards making it an enjoyable project to work on. Is there something I did wrong here or steps I may have missed? Is there people here that figured out similar problems?

Thanks a lot, any help is greatly appreciated!

Frederik

**Update - 2016/07/28:**

Digging into the code itself, I found that the first error is caused by `::FreeLibrary (in module_list.cc)` not being able to correctly free the HMODULE. Sorry for putting code here, if this can help I prefer to let it here.

*Current investigation: build a new version that resort on `::UnMapViewOfFile` when `::FreeLibrary` fails to see if it gets through the first errors.*

For the second error, I still have no idea of what is going on. Going to continue investigation, hoping to find more potential details.

Please feel free to ask for any information that could help resolve the issues.

**Update 2 - 2016/07/28:**

I've asked a different, more programming-oriented question on StackOverflow, if it can help:
[Chromium-browser build fatal errors in module_list.cc: Check Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635546/chromium-browser-build-fatal-errors-in-module-list-cc-check-failed)

**Update 3 - 2016/07/29**

I finally got something working!! What did it is configuring the build with these configurations in args.gn:

`> gn args out/Default`

```
is_debug = false
enable_nacl = false
symbol_level = 0
remove_webcore_debug_symbols = true
```

This configuration isn't viable for debugging, but having a working configuration is a huge step forward. Super happy right now!! My current hypothesis would be that it has to do something with the debug flag. Can it be that internal function calls have trouble accessing the right module names in debug mode?

**Update 4 - 2016/08/13**

After a fresh debug build, I noticed that few Windows Kit debugger DLLs were not copied in the build directory. This time, the linking process failed on `api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll`. I then copied all of them hoping it would resolve all the issues. On the first run, the errors didn't show up, but the same behavior occured when I performed a right-click on the Google Homepage (browsing mechanics broken silently). After closing and reopening it, the same errors are back.

Anyone as an idea to resolve those issues or any different procedures then the ones on the chromium project?

Comment: Having the stack traces as images only is unhelpful.  Can you put one on Pastebin at least, if you don't feel good about including it inline in the question as text?

Comment: @tripleee I will do my best to retrieve or pipe the errors next week to be able to efficiently copy/paste them.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to request you to set your **Windows**, **environment** for Visual Studio, and get the compiler **toolchain** correctly. Please follow the steps in the link below, and try everything with the latest version including updates. 
Please find the link here: **[Windows Build Instruction](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md)**

For your reference, please find the snapshots of build Chromium here: **[Snapshots of Chromium](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html)**

Let me know if it helps you even a bit. 
Thank you.

Comment: I double checked the configurations. The only thing I have different is that I actually have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 instead of Update 2. Can it be that bad and worth downgrading VS and building chromium from the beginning? It takes quite a bit of time to rebuild everything, so I try to take clever guesses :) As for the snapshots, thanks, I was able to test with the latest 408050 and was able to run it without the errors I've got with my own build. So it probably is my fault.

Comment: Yes, I can understand the pain of starting again from the beginning. But you have to understand that your current configuration is also not working properly. So why not try everything while you could? Who knows this time you could find something much more interesting that worth the starting?

Comment: I will revert to VS 2015 Update 2 and run a clean build during the night to see if it helps and will give some feedback when it's done. Thanks for your advices, it helps me a lot! I indeed find new helpful configurations each time I start over. Hopefully the steps are safer now since I wrapped the project inside a Node.js skeleton.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. I hope this time you succeed. Good luck.

Comment: As far as I went into this, microsoft doesn't allow you to update to a given number prior to the latest. All the online installers links have the same file id, the offline ones will give obscure compatibility errors. It seems that for a moment it was possible to achieve this by mounting an iso image. However, the one remaining iso image I've found is a broken link. Is there any way to achieve this seemingly simple update? I prefer not to install a crack or anything dirty if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Just a little update: I started over, even though I wasn't able to explicitly use Update 2. I uninstalled all VS updates and reinstalled them (which forced me to use Update 3). I updated my checkout to the last revision, synced and runned the hooks. I then deleted all my src/out/Default directory and runned a `gn gen out/Default` again and rebuilt everything. I still have the mentionnned issues at runtime. Is it even a possibility that such a long build cannot detect a single error, yet fails at runtime? I mean, compilation goes fine, suggesting that my build setup is correct. Any idea?

Comment: I tried deploying a minimalist version of my build in AppData/Local/Chromium/Application to see if it would fix something with this path configuration, but issues are still occuring. This is very puzzling, I feel like there is some obscure configurations to do around the workspace once it is built. That would be worth clarifying the documentation when those issues are figured out. Thanks again for helping me on that.

Comment: What I want to suggest, looks like you've already figured it out. It's good that you're still trying. The problem is to help you completely, I atleast need to try the whole process again by myself. And I very much like to do so, but I have to wait till Sunday. Till then I will request you to as you've started it, try to finish it and please keep me updated. I'll try to figure it out this Sunday. Thank you Frederik.

Comment: Hey, got something working! (see my last update). The only remaining thing is finding why this works in release mode but fails in debug mode. We are getting very close! I will be able to continue testing from next monday (2016-07-30) because I have an exam tomorrow and away from computer until then. I will still be able to answer questions about what my build configuration is, though.

Comment: Finally some good news. Keep trying and I'll wait for your reply. Thanks.

Comment: I've got a new fresh build in debug mode (see Update 4) and found something. I am starting to think that the build is broken on Windows. Is it possible? Are you aware if people out there prefer to work on Linux? I've seen organizations that would stop debugging windows build because the Linux one is working better lmao. Thanks!